# What is the best way to reload a child tableview contained within a parent VC that is being fed fresh data?

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates

I have been playing with the concept of the parent/child view delegation for a few days now, and currently understand how to feed data from parent to child. However, now, I want a button in the parent (main VC) to reload the data presented in the child VC.

I'm trying to delegate a method that is activated in the child VC's class but is activated in the parent's navigation controller. So that when I press the button, the delegated method in the child VC is performed; in my case, that method would be reload table. Why am I getting so many errors when trying to set up this simple delegation relationship?

My parent/container View is currently delegating a method to the child, so I have it set up from child -> parent. But I want to set it up from parent -> child. Pretty much I have:

```
struct Constants {
    static let embedSegue = "containerToCollectionView"
}


class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, CollectionViewControllerDelegate {

func giveMeData(collectionViewController: CollectionViewController) {
    println("This data will be passed")
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == Constants.embedSegue {
        let childViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CollectionViewController
        childViewController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

FROM CHILD:

```
protocol CollectionViewControllerDelegate {
    func giveMeData(collectionViewController: CollectionViewController)
}

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate:CollectionViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.delegate?.giveMeData(self)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I think my trouble is the fact that I'm declaring the child delegate in a prepareforsegue, so that was straight forward, but now I want the reverse delegation. How do I set that up so that I can use a child-method from the parent VC?

Answer (score 0):

The child view controller has no business supplying other controllers with data. It should actually not even have any data fetching logic that is so generic it is also used by other controllers. You should refactor the data methods out into a new class.

This pattern is called Model-View-Controller, or MVC, and is a very basic concept that you should understand and follow. Apple explains it [pretty well](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html).

In general, to send data to from a controller to a detail controller, use `prepareForSegue` to set properties, etc. To communicate back to the parent controller, you use delegate protocols, but usually these are called when the detail controller is finished with its work and just reports the result up to the parent.

If you want to update the detail VC with new data (without dismissing it and with the parent not visible) you should not put the logic to update it into the parent. Instead, use the structure suggested above.

Comment: I just want to be able to refresh a table in the child VC which I can control on the parent's navigation controller. Hence, I just want to be able to delegate a simple method which can be activated on the parent's VC class. I'm not feeding data from the Child to parent. In fact, it's the other way around.

Comment: Please read the linked documentation about MVC. You will find that you will not need what you describe. Nevertheless, I will add a hint of how you communicate between controllers to my answer.